# Oracle SQL - If Exists, Drop Table & Create

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can some one please guide me what's wrong with this query? In SQL Server we just check the presence of the Object_ID of a table to drop it and re-create it. I am new to Oracle and wrote this query:

```
declare Table_exists INTEGER;
 BEGIN
 Select count(*) into Table_exists from sys.all_tables where table_name='TABLENAME1';
 EXCEPTION
          WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
          THEN
          Table_Exists :=0;
if(table_exists)=1
  Then
  Execute Immediate 'Drop Table TABLENAME1;'
  'Create Table TABLENAME1;';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table Dropped and Re-Created!');
Else 
     Execute Immediate 'Create Table TABLENAME1;';
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('New Table Created!');
END IF;
END;
```

I get the output - ANONYMOUS BLOCK COMPLETED, but the table is not created. The table was previously existing, so I dropped it to check if the PL/SQL is actually creating the table, but NO. What is wrong here? What am I missing? Please guide.

Comment: Four issues: 1) you don't have an `Execute Immediate` in front of your first create table. 2) your create table statements don't include columns. 3) your if then else block is inside and therefore part of your exception handler. 4) aggregate queries always return at least 1 row so your exception handler will never get called and your code will never run.

Comment: @Sentinel :  4) aggregate queries always return at least 1 row so your exception handler will never get called and your code will never run - Thanks for highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EXCEPTION clause lasts till the next END and not just the next statement. If you want to continue after catching the exception you need to add an additional BEGIN/END:

```
declare 
    Table_exists INTEGER; 
BEGIN 
    BEGIN
        Select count(*) into Table_exists from sys.all_tables where table_name='TABLENAME1'; 
    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
        Table_Exists :=0; 
    END;

    if(table_exists)=1 Then 
        Execute Immediate 'Drop Table TABLENAME1;'     
        Execute Immediate 'Create Table TABLENAME1;'; 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table Dropped and Re-Created!'); 
    Else 
        Execute Immediate 'Create Table TABLENAME1;'; 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('New Table Created!'); 
    END IF; 
END;
```

As pointed out by Gordon, the EXCEPTION clause is not really needed in this case since `count(*)` will always return one row. So the following is sufficient:

```
declare 
    Table_exists INTEGER; 
BEGIN 
    Select count(*) into Table_exists from sys.all_tables where table_name='TABLENAME1'; 

    if(table_exists)=1 Then 
        Execute Immediate 'Drop Table TABLENAME1;'     
        Execute Immediate 'Create Table TABLENAME1;'; 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table Dropped and Re-Created!'); 
    Else 
        Execute Immediate 'Create Table TABLENAME1;'; 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('New Table Created!'); 
    END IF; 
END;
```

Comment: Great! Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `all_tables` filter the results for your
schema by adding   `where owner = 'your_schema'`
or use `sys.user_tables`

> ALL_TABLES describes the relational tables accessible to the current user
>
> USER_TABLES describes the relational tables owned by the current user.

When use `execute_emmidiate` remove the `;` from the query;

Modified query;

```
DECLARE 
    Table_exists INTEGER;
BEGIN
    Select count(*) into Table_exists from sys.user_tables where table_name='TABLENAME1';
    --or
    --Select count(*) into Table_exists from sys.all_tables 
    --where table_name='TABLENAME1' and owner = 'your_DB';
    if table_exists = 1 Then
        Execute Immediate 'Drop Table TABLENAME1';
        Execute Immediate 'Create Table TABLENAME1(num number)';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table Dropped and Re-Created!');
    Else 
        Execute Immediate 'Create Table TABLENAME1(num number)';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('New Table Created!');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Hey, that worked. Looks like the EXCEPTION HANDLING was causing the issue. I had dropped the table prior to executing the PLSQL. So the script executed saying - "New Table Created!". When I executed it again, I was expecting "Table Dropped and Re-Created!", but I got an error - "name is already used by an existing object". So the first part of the Execute Immediate didnt trigger? Why is that? Any idea?

Comment: This is the correct answer. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_exceptions.htm has some information on exceptions. You could have debugged your script by outputting the table_exists variable and seen that it was blank.

Answer (score 1):

First note:

```
Select count(*) into Table_exists
from sys.all_tables
where table_name = 'TABLENAME1';
```

will *always* return one row.  You don't need the exception handling.

My best guess is that you have more than one table called `TABLENAME1`.  Run this query to find out:

```
Select *
from sys.all_tables
where table_name = 'TABLENAME1';
```

Oracle stores tables from all owners that you can access.  You might also want to check `OWNER_NAME` in the `where` clause.

However, you seem to understand exception handling.  So, just drop the table, ignore any errors, and then recreate the table.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. There is no TableName1 in the schema. I have verified it. I would want to follow this coding standard so that all developers in team stick to it when they send scripts to the DBA for execution. That was how I did when I worked in SQL Server. The DBA would not execute scripts if he did not find an If Exists - Drop - Create syntax in the script.

Comment: @SidhuRam . . . Your missing the point.  `sys.all_tables` is checking *all* schemas, not just the current schema.  Although this behavior is the same on SQL Server, it seems different, because Oracle really has only one database per server.  What look like separate databases are really just separate schemas inside the database.

Comment: Gordon, Thanks for the explanation. In SQL Server, we can create multiple databases on the same server. I thought the architecture in Oracle would be the same. Thanks for highlighting the difference.